# What is the correct SQL script for my desired output?

Tags: sql-server-2000

This is my Script

```
SELECT '' AS [DATE],'' AS [INCOMING],'' AS [OUTGOING],BegBal AS [BALANCE] 
  FROM TABLE1 WHERE ItemCode='Item1'
UNION ALL
SELECT DelDate as [DATE],'' AS [INCOMING],Qty as [OUTGOING],'' 
  FROM Table2 WHERE ItemCode='Item1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT RecDate AS [DATE],Qty as [INCOMING],'' as [OUTGOING],'' 
  FROM Table3 WHERE ItemCode='Item1'
```

and my result is

```
DATE       INCOMING OUTGOING  BALANCE
1900-01-01  0.0      0.0      100.0
2014-06-05  0.0      2.0      0.0
2014-06-14  10.0     0.0      0.0
```

and I want my result to be like this

```
DATE       INCOMING OUTGOING  BALANCE
1900-01-01  0.0      0.0      100.0
2014-06-05  0.0      2.0      98
2014-06-14  10.0     0.0      108
```

Comment: @olanyer have you tried answer proposed? Could you accept it, if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @balance int
declare @outgoing int

SELECT @balance=sum(BegBal) FROM TABLE1 WHERE ItemCode='Item1'
SELECT @outgoing=sum(Qty) FROM Table2 WHERE ItemCode='Item1'

SELECT '' AS [DATE],'' AS [INCOMING],'' AS [OUTGOING],BegBal AS [BEGINING BALANCE] 
FROM TABLE1 WHERE ItemCode='Item1'
UNION ALL
SELECT DelDate as [DATE],'' AS [INCOMING],Qty as [OUTGOING],@balance-Qty 
FROM Table2 WHERE ItemCode='Item1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT RecDate AS [DATE],Qty as [INCOMING],'' as [OUTGOING],@balance+Qty-@outgoing 
FROM Table3 WHERE ItemCode='Item1'
```